# Rest API calls from the Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating the ASP.NET which is calling a third party Rest API. The third party API can be accessed only giving username and password. Also uses Http Basic Authentication

```
 public string Get(string LabName)
   {
    string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
    string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
    string BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
        client.BaseAddress = uri;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        string clarity_URL = BaseURL+"api/v2/labs?name="+LabName;
        var response = client.GetAsync(clarity_URL).Result;

        string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return responseString;
```

Should I be using `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.I am not sure how to pass the username and password while calling the Rest API in the ASP.NET.Can anyone suggest me how to securely call the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Comment: Since I have the String userName tried giving `var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName:password);` it throws error like `Error 1 The best overload for 'GetBytes' does not have a parameter named 'userName' 
`

Comment: You should go like `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username+":"+password);`

Comment: @user4912134 if you think this answer was the right solution, kindly mark it as answered. :)